# Handling large excel files in UIWebView

Tags: xcode, ipad, excel, uiwebview

I have an iPad app that downloads excel files using an `NSURLConnection` and then renders the downloaded file in a `UIWebView`.

The implementation works fine for smaller sized files but increasingly begins to struggle as I approach excel files of about 5 MB.

I'm testing this on a 3rd generation iPad, which has 1 GB of RAM.
The downloaded files are written in the `NSCachesDirectory` folder.

I also tried to increase the cache memory size by using the `setSharedURLCache` method, but this doesn't help.

Any solution to this?

Comment: I have an app that downloads XL files to a custom folder in documents directory. It seems to handle large files OK, albeit they take a little longer to open.

Comment: There's a 45-second gap between the UIWebView delegate method `webviewDidStartLoad` being called and the document actually becoming visible (and webviewDidFinishLoad is never called, perhaps because this is a local file?).
Did you explicitly optimize the UIWebView to handle large files in some way?

Comment: No, just: `self.myWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024)];
    [_myWebView loadRequest:_service.myExcelURLRequest];
    [self.view addSubview:_myWebView];` where `_service` is based on code provided in this tutorial: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/design-build-a-small-business-app-custom-detail-views/

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I notice that this problem is not just with my app's UIWebView but also the native Safari app...